# Autocomplete do override C# não funciona

Tags: c#, visual-studio, método, autocompletar, sobrescrita

Não consigo realizar uma sobrescrita com sugestões do `override`.

O autocomplete do método do `override` não dá sugestões de virtual classes ou métodos como *ToString()*.

Como faço pra que essas sugestões apareçam?

Esse é o método de minha superclasse que quero sobrescrever em minha subclasse:

```
public virtual void Withdraw(double amount)
    {
        Balance -= amount + 5.0;
    }
```

Em minha subclasse, não aparecem sugestões como `ToString()` ou o método *Withdraw()* da superclasse:

[image: Não aparecem sugestões como ToString() ou o método da superclasse]

Comment: Isso é uma dúvida sobre o editor. Qual você está usando?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Método override de que classe? Como está seu código exatamente?

Comment: Eu possuo um método virtual em uma superclasse e quero sobrescrevê-lo em uma subclasse. Na minha subclasse, ao digitar override, esse método virtual não aparece como sugestão para autocompletar, e tenho que digitar manualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após a palavra chave `override` não deve vir o nome do método, tem algumas outras possibilidades do que pode escrever aí e estão listadas no *autocomplete* na sua imagem, quando usar mais alguma coisa no código pode ser (depende do que usar em seguida) que a próxima palavra a ser usada seja o nome de um método que permite a sobrescrita, se isto ocorrer aparecerá os nomes dos métodos. Portando está funcionando corretamente. E mesmo que não estivesse ainda poderia escrever o código normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente está faltando um plug in do visual studio para ele identificar a linguagem e autocompletar. Caso já tenha instalado um plug in, talvez necessite escrever um comando específico do plug in para fazê-lo funcionar. 
EX: se escrever `Prop` ao programar em C#, se estiver com o plug in da microsoft instalado, ele autocompleta para criar uma variável, te permitindo alterar os valores apenas apertando TAB